# How to convert text of the form Month-Year to date format?

Tags: google-sheets, date

How do I convert the text "Oct-14" to date, so that it's being read as "Oct 01, 2014. I tried to go to Format > Date and selected the format: Oct-2014, but google sheets is interpreting it as "Oct 14, 2016". I just need the month and year (Oct-2014).

[Here's the sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18wUcq_zBV4MdcXTUShYl7N2cx_TBVq9EONSIGvVlsuk/edit#gid=0): I need help with columns B and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
=datevalue("01-"&B2)
```

(single-cell formula that can be copied down), or

```
=arrayformula(datevalue("01-"&B2:B))
```

(converts an entire column at once), or

```
=arrayformula(iferror(datevalue("01-"&B2:B)))
```

(does the same, while suppressing any error messages).

This works because the strings like 01-Oct-14 are understood by `datevalue` command correctly, at least in your locale.